# Adding and deleting multiple fields in a nested object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, object, nested

I have this MongoDB data which I have inserted this way:

```
db.orders.insert({ _id: ObjectId().str, name: "admin", status: "online",catalog : [
    {
        "objectid" : ObjectId().str,
        "message" : "sold",
        "status" : "open"
    }
]})
```

First, I want to add new fields to the catalog object which I am doing like this:

```
db.orders.update({"_id":"5703b86df3d607cb5fa75ff3"},{$set: {"catalog.0.day": "tuesday"},{"catalog.0.payments": "paypal"}});
```

That code fails with this error:

```
2016-04-05T16:48:41.757+0300 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell):1:88
```

I also want to delete some fields and I am preparing to do so with this code:

```
db.orders.update({"_id":"5703b86df3d607cb5fa75ff3"},{$unset: {"catalog.0.day": ""},{"catalog.0.payments": ""}});
```

Why is the update statement failing and how can I delete the fields I have added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to `$set`:

```
db.orders.update(
    {"_id":"5703b86df3d607cb5fa75ff3"},
    {$set: {
            "catalog.0.day": "tuesday",
            "catalog.0.payments": "paypal"
        }
    });
```

And this to `$unset`:

```
db.orders.update(
    {"_id":"5703b86df3d607cb5fa75ff3"},
    {
        $unset: {
            "catalog.0.day": "",
            "catalog.0.payments": ""
        }
    });
```

If you want to use just one update call, then you can do this:

```
db.orders.update(
    {"_id":"5703b86df3d607cb5fa75ff3"},
    {
        $unset: {
            "catalog.0.day": "",
            "catalog.0.payments": ""
        },
        $set: {
            "catalog.0.day": "tuesday",
            "catalog.0.payments": "paypal"
        }
    });
```

If you want multiple records, then:

```
db.orders.update(
    {"status":"online"},
    {
        $unset: {
            "catalog.0.day": "",
            "catalog.0.payments": ""
        },
        $set: {
            "catalog.0.day": "tuesday",
            "catalog.0.payments": "paypal"
        }
    },
    {
        multi: true
    });
```

Note that in this one, my query document has changed to a more general field. and NOT `_id`

Comment: The two queries work.A qucik one though. Lets say i have a collecion wihh 100 records. In mysql,i could update the 100 records if i new the field i was updating and left out the specific id,meaning all the 100 rows wold be updated. Is here such a provision in mongo,to enable me update the 100 records with just one query?.

Comment: Thats for your help.